# Can I get a proper wordlist for Google Doc's spellcheck?

Tags: google-drive, google-docs, spell-check

I'm trying to use Google Docs for academic writing, and it marks words like "Ilion", "iconophobia" or "wrothful" as incorrect.

Making sure I didn't misspell any of these and manually adding each one has gotten very annoying.
Is there any way I can get a proper, complete OED-level spell checking in Google Docs?

Answer (score 1):

No, I'm afraid except for adding words manually, there is no way to customize the dictionary used by Google Docs.